# How to have java lambda functions with members just like C++ lambda functions?

Tags: java, lambda

```
public interface FrameAcquirer {
    public ByteBuffer onAcquireNewFrame();
}
```

I want to create `FrameAcquirer` instances that implement the onAcquireNewFrame lambda function, but I want it to have internal components, just like C++:

```
public class FfmpegFrameAcquirer implements FrameAcquirer {
    int id;
    public FfmpegFrameAcquirer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ByteBuffer onAcquireNewFrame() {
        return onAcquireNewFrameFfmpeg(id);
    }
    public native ByteBuffer onAcquireNewFrameFfmpeg(int id);
}
```

But in order to create a `FrameAcquirer` lambda function I should do this

```
FrameAcquirer myFrameAcquirerFunction = () -> {return null;}
```

There's no place to initiate my `FfmpegFrameAcquirer` with its id.

In C++ I'd simply do

```
FrameAcquirer myFrameAcquirerFunction = [id](){return nullptr;}
```

Comment: You're not using `id` so what's the point? If you were to use it, Java implicitly captures the variable for you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using it when I do `return onAcquireNewFrameFfmpeg(id);`

Comment: I mean in your lambda version. Lambda capture is implicit in Java. `myFrameAcquirerFunction  = () -> ByteBuffer.allocate(id);` or whateveryou want to do with the `id`.